# Installing libCurl - ruby 1.9.3 .. rails 3.2.12 .. Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, libcurl, curb, feedzirra

So, I'm trying to get feedzirra up and running... `ruby 1.9.3p448` `Rails 3.2.12`

- I went to http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32 and downloaded `Win32 2000/XP 7.32.0 libcurl SSL`. It may be obvious, but this is  `libcurl -v 7.32`.
- I unzipped the aforementioned file into `c:\libcurl` ( so the bin, lib, and whatnot are directly in libcurl ).
- I added `c:\libcurl\bin` to the `PATH`.
- While in my app's working directory, I told bundler where to find the cURL dependencies with `bundle config build.curb --with-curl-lib=C:\libcurl\bin --with-curl-include=C:\libcurl\include`.
- I set the version of nokogiri to `gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.3'` in my gemfile, as it doesn't like the current -v 1.6.0.  This installs `nokogiri -v 1.5.10`.
- I set the version of feedzirra to `gem 'feedzirra', github: 'pauldix/feedzirra', ref: '80cd357'` in my gemfile.
- This installs some dependencies:

  Using curb (0.8.4) - trying `gem 'curb', '0.8.1'` and `gem 'curb', '~> 0.7.15'` doesn't resolve the issue, just a heads up

  Using loofah (1.2.1)

  Using sax-machine (0.2.0.rc1)

  Using feedzirra (0.2.0.rc2) from git://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra.git (at 80cd357) - obviously

`bundle` is a success! Problem isn't with `bundle`, though.  I can get the stuff to install.  When trying `rails s` or `rails c`, I get the following: ( `curb_core.so` does exist, though )

```
APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Dropbox/Apps/rails_projects/ecorebox/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.4/lib/curb_core.so (LoadError)
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.4/lib/curl.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.4/lib/curb.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/feedzirra-021a8d7f53d7/lib/feedzirra.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from APP_FOLDER/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
from APP_FOLDER/.bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummmm.  **I rebooted.**  For anyone ending up here... the question is the answer.  Plus a reboot.  I didn't know I had to reboot with this stuff?  I'm not gonna fight it!  Woot!!